# Phrasing "The relevant framework becomes X"

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm writing a piece in which at some point there is a shift to a new subject called stochastic dynamical systems. The transition looks like follows

> ...but once dynamical noise is introduced the relevant mathematical
> framework becomes *stochastic dynamical systems*.

But this doesn't sound quite right to me. I've considered the following alternative

> ...but once dynamical noise is introduced the relevant mathematical
> framework becomes **that of** *stochastic dynamical systems*.

Is there a better way of phrasing this?

If there are more appropriate tags for this question please feel free to add them.

Comment: Does the sentence mean "When xyz is introduced , we have to apply a new  framework to the problem"  , `or` "When xyz is introduced , the framework transforms into something else?" (Latter does not seem a plausible option, but even then it's better to know)

Comment: @R.S. The former.

Comment: Yes, the mismatch of number is jarring, and adding padding (I wish I hadn'r said that) makes things less incongruous. _Distance lends enchantment to the view._  Another solution:  'but once dynamical noise is introduced the relevant mathematical framework becomes the _stochastic dynamical systems_ model.

Comment: stochastic dynamic systems

Comment: @Xanne  Yes, I thought that too, but [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=stochastic+dynamical+systems) steamrolled the puritan in me with over a million results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would insert a short reason for the transition before mentioning  the new framework. Something like -

> ...but once dynamical noise is introduced the added randomness (or
> whatever) takes  the process/problem  into the realm of another
> framework, called stochastic dynamical systems.

If the reader is already familiar with the new framework then we can drop 'another framework` bit and the flow of sentence becomes even smoother.

> ...but once dynamical noise is introduced the added randomness (or
> whatever) takes  the process/problem  into the realm/domain of stochastic dynamical systems.